# Re-render a component which is a part of a table row in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a table of "servers", each server row in a table has a timer component which counts how long a server is running, and a toggle button to make it active or in-active. My problem is that when I press the button I change the server "IsRunning" literal to false, but the timer doesn't re-render. The timer is running only when "server.IsRunning" is true. Does anyone have any idea how to make my timer to re-render so it would stop counting?

Here is my table Render Row code, I put my Timer component on the second "<td" and the toggler button in the third:

```
RenderServerRow({ servers, onClick, TogglerFunction }) {
        return (
            servers.map((server) => 
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" colSpan = "1">{server.ip}</th>
                <td colSpan = "2">{server.servername}</td>
                <td colSpan = "2"><Timer IsRunning = {server.IsRunning}/></td>
                <td colSpan = "2"><Button color="primary" onClick={() => TogglerFunction(server.id)}>Toggle</Button></td>
                <td colSpan = "1">{server.Type}</td>
                <td colSpan = "2">0</td>
                <td colSpan = "2"> <Button color="primary" onClick={() => onClick(server.id)}>Delete</Button></td>
                {<td onClick={() => onClick(server.id)} colSpan = "2">0</td>}
            </tr>)
        );
    }
```

Here is an image which shows how it looks like:

[image]

You can see that the first server is running and the second ain't, I'm trying to get my toggle button to works for hours now. It manages to change the server.IsRunning literal, but the timer keeps on running.

Comment: Have you looked into `useEffect`, since you want your component to be mounted again after some change in data

Comment: @A.K.M.Adib Hmm I have read about useEffect, but since the values I want to change are in a completely different component in a different file, I'm not sure how or what hooks I can use.

Comment: @mashtock [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) is what you are looking for.